# Read variable value of remote document using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two HTML files: `html1.htm` and `html2.htm`.

The code `html1.htm`:

```
<script>
$("#ajax").load("html2.htm");
</script>
```

In `html2.htm`:

```
<script>
var x=10;
</script>
```

How can I get the value of `x` in html1.htm?

If X is changing all the time in html2.htm how to get its value updated in html1.htm?

Comment: If `x` is indeed declared in the global scope. You'll be able to access it simply by using `x` (*after* the asynchronous call ended successfully).

Answer (score 4):

jQuery's `.load()` will execute embedded scripts in the content.  So, if `x` is in the global scope, then you can directly access the variable `x` after the `.load()` completes:

```
<script>
$("#ajax").load("html2.htm", function() {
    console.log(x);
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, If X is changing all the time in html2.htm how to get its value updated in html1.htm?

Comment: @ruti - once html2.htm is loaded into html1.htm, there is only one variable named `x` and it's in html1.htm because that's the host document.  html2.htm no longer exists - it is just a piece of content in html1.htm.